# iOS frameworks containing simulator slices can't be submitted to the App Store

Tags: ios, architecture, frameworks

There is an open [radar](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6409498411401216) for this issue and I'm a little confused by the whole thing.

I have created Fat libraries before and not noticed an issue like this. However, for carthage it was a big [issue](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/188) for them.

If I create a framework that I was to integrate with one of my own Apps, the onus is on me to strip the i386 simulator architecture from that Framework when archiving for the App store ?

If I create a framework that I want to give / sell to a client, I have to inform them to do the same ? Ultimately, I want the client to be able to run my framework on the simulator and on a device, before they integrate it and submit to the App store.